# pivot_wider command generates a list() instead of a "wider" data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, pivot

I have data.frame with two columns the first shows the value of a year and the second the epoch.

I use the pivot_wider command to create two columns: one with only rainy season values and one with dry season. However, I got as a result an object of type list() with two vector elements, one with the values of the rainy season and the other of the dry season. This object cannot convert to data.frame format with two dry and rainy columns, even using the `as.data.frame()` command.

`dput`

> ```
> df<-structure(list(corr = c(0.74744744694889, 0.74744744694889, -0.74744744694889, 
> 0.710707994222, -0.672727272727273, -0.627272727272727, 0.721341509883808, 
> 0.74744744694889, 0.74744744694889, -0.74744744694889, 0.710707994222, 
> -0.672727272727273, -0.627272727272727, 0.721341509883808, 0.74744744694889, 
> 0.74744744694889, -0.74744744694889, 0.706152173746218, -0.690909090909091, 
> -0.627272727272727, 0.721341509883808, -0.569861483395246, -0.721861340047052, 
> 0.609081215121124, 0.74744744694889, 0.74744744694889, -0.74744744694889, 
> 0.664332608058143, 0.683373071367308, 0.608092810550575, -0.745454545454545, 
> 0.74744744694889, 0.74744744694889, -0.74744744694889, 0.664332608058143, 
> 0.683373071367308, 0.608092810550575, -0.745454545454545, -0.836363636363636, 
> -0.74744744694889, 0.695967494156149, 0.608092810550575, 0.824603506116551, 
> 0.74744744694889, 0.74744744694889, -0.556029893992449, -0.682125853438958, 
> 0.556029893992449, 0.729285774909194), season = c("wet", "wet", 
> "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
> "dry", "dry", "dry", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
> "wet", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
> "dry", "dry", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
> "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "dry", "dry", 
> "dry", "dry")), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = "data.frame")
> ```

I tryed this:

```
  df2<-df%>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = season, values_from = corr)
```

output

[image]

I would like to get a dataframe with only two columns:
wet and dry and their respective values.

Comment: If you had the same number of `wet` and `dry` you could `... %>% unnest()`. But you have 21 dry values and 28 wet values. Data frame columns must have the same length.

Comment: Got it, could he fill with NA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `id` column and things get easier:

```
df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number(), .by = season) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = season, values_from = corr, id_cols = id)
# # A tibble: 28 × 3
#       id    wet    dry
#    <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1     1  0.747  0.747
#  2     2  0.747  0.747
#  3     3 -0.747 -0.747
#  4     4  0.711  0.711
#  5     5 -0.673 -0.673
#  6     6 -0.627 -0.627
#  7     7  0.721  0.721
#  8     8  0.747 -0.570
#  9     9  0.747 -0.722
# 10    10 -0.747  0.609
# # … with 18 more rows
```